# yii 1 Проверка существования пользователя

Tags: php, yii

Есть rules    ( yii1 )
в нем правило

```
 ['lastname, firstname, midname', 'length', 'max' => 80]
```

Как проверить есть ли пользователь с таким именем и фамилией?:

Comment: yii1 или yii2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте кастомный валидатор в таком случае:

```
['lasttname', 'checkUnique'],
```

И ниже в файле валидатора метод:

```
public function checkUnique($attribute, $params) {
        $user = Users::model()->findByAttributes([
            'lastname' => $this->lastname,
            'firstname' => $this->firstname,
            'midname' => $this->midname,
        ]);

        if ($user !== null) {
            $this->addError($attribute, 'Такой пользователь уже существует');
        }
    }
```

Comment: он не должен быть уникальныйм по отдельности, вместе , имя фамилия отчество , нужно вывести предупреждение , если такой уже существует. Я не знаю как это реализовать синтаксисом yii1

Comment: Надеюсь я теперь правильно понял вопрос